mi reporte se imprime sin data
estoy intentando generar un reporte en pdf desde java, donde estoy utilizando una plantilla .jasper que fue creada con JasperSoft Studio, pero esta plantilla esta guardada en un repositorio de filenet, por lo cual consumo un servicio que me trae la plantilla donde el Content-Type: application/octet-stream.
Actualmente me imprime el pdf, pero me lo retorna sin data

Mi código esta distribuido de esta manera. Estos son los ajustes que realice. Anteriormente trabajaba con las plantillas pero desde la carpeta resources de mi proyecto. Pero ahora me lo han pedido de esta manera. Obteniendo la plantilla desde el fileNet
public byte[] generarReporteProvisiones(@NotNull ReporteModel reporteModel) throws JRException, IOException {
    // Realizar la llamada HTTP para obtener la plantilla
    String url = apiDocumento + "?ecmDocumentoId=40D85C91-0000-CC13-ADE2-54D28C9CB596";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, byte[].class);

    System.out.println("Respuesta endpoint: " + response.getStatusCode());

    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        byte[] jasperBytes = response.getBody();

        // Objetos y variables inicializados
        Integer cantidadPersonas = 0;
        EscalaModel escalaModel;
        EscalaSeguimientoModel escalaSeguimientoModel;
        boolean isArribo = false;
        boolean isZarpe = false;
        String nombreAgencia = "";
        String nombrePuerto = "";
        String bandera = "";
        List<ListaProvisionModel> listaProvisiones;

        // Asignar los valores
        Integer cantidadTripulantes = tripulanteService.cantidadTripulantes(reporteModel.getEscalaId(), reporteModel.getTipo());
        Integer cantidadPasajeros = pasajeroService.cantidadPasajeros(reporteModel.getEscalaId(), reporteModel.getTipo());
        cantidadPersonas = cantidadPasajeros + cantidadTripulantes;
        listaProvisiones = provisionService.listarProviciones(reporteModel.getEscalaId(), reporteModel.getTipo());
        escalaSeguimientoModel = escalaSeguimientoService.obtenerFechaEmision(reporteModel.getEscalaId(), reporteModel.getTipo());

        if (reporteModel.getTipo().equals("E")) {
            escalaModel = escalaService.obtenerDatosEscalaArribo(reporteModel.getEscalaId());
        } else {
            escalaModel = escalaService.obtenerDatosEscalaZarpe(reporteModel.getEscalaId());
        }

        Long tiempoEntreAtaYAtd = escalaModel.getTiempoEntreAtaYAtd().toMillis();

        nombrePuerto = escalaService.obtenerPuerto(reporteModel.getEscalaId());

        bandera = escalaService.obtenerBandera(reporteModel.getEscalaId(), reporteModel.isSpanish());

        if (escalaModel.getTipoNave().equals("20")) {
            nombreAgencia = escalaService.obtenerAdministrador(reporteModel.getEscalaId());
        } else {
            nombreAgencia = escalaService.obtenerAgencia(reporteModel.getEscalaId());
        }

        // Parametros para el reporte
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("nombreNave", escalaModel.getNombreNave());
        // Demas parametros...

        if (reporteModel.getTipo().equals("E")) {
            isArribo = true;
            parametros.put("isArribo", isArribo);
            parametros.put("isZarpe", isZarpe);
        } else {
            isZarpe = true;
            parametros.put("isArribo", isArribo);
            parametros.put("isZarpe", isZarpe);
        }

        // Verificar los valores de los parámetros
        System.out.println("Parámetros enviados al reporte:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parametros.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Parámetro: " + entry.getKey() + " - Valor: " + entry.getValue());
        }

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaProvisiones);

        // Cargar el archivo .jasper desde el flujo de bytes
        InputStream jasperStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jasperBytes);
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);

        // Llenar el reporte
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros, dataSource);

        // Exportar a PDF
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfReportStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, pdfReportStream);

        return pdfReportStream.toByteArray();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error al descargar la plantilla Jasper desde el endpoint");
    }
}


Se ha de suponer que los valores se asignan correctamente??? deberías mostrar el system.out con los valores cargados, y si han aparecido todos. Hasta donde veo, es como si los parámetros jamás se hubieran asignado, no han llehado ni vacios, ni llenos de nada, no existen en el pdf.

gracias por la respuesta. Si tengo conocimiento que como declaro los parámetros debe ser igual a como declaro mis parametros en el jasper soft studio. Y comentar tambien que si le estoy mandando informacion a esos parametros.

Par�metros enviados al reporte:
Par�metro: numeroViaje - Valor:
Par�metro: nombrePuerto - Valor: PE - CALLAO
Par�metro: ultimoPuerto - Valor: CL - PUERTO CISNES
Par�metro: imo - Valor: IMO9431719
Par�metro: fechaEmision - Valor: 2024-08-15 21:00:03.990386
Par�metro: callSign - Valor: CALLSIGN12
Par�metro: ata - Valor: 2024-08-05 13:40:31.0
Par�metro: atd - Valor: null
Par�metro: nombreNave - Valor: PAE
Le hice un System.out.println y como puedes ver si le estoy dando valores

Edita la publicación y agregalos ahi amigo jaja
